# Alternative for matlabpool

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am trying to use someone else's code and there is this line in it:

```
if (m<100) || (matlabpool('size')==0)
```

I am using MATLAB R2016a, so this command fails. What is the equivalent of `matlabpool('size')` in the new version?

I know that `matlabpool` is replaced by `parpool`. But what does `matlabpool('size')` do specifically? It doesn't actually create the parallel workers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [change log](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2015a&endrelease=R2015a):

> `matlabpool` function removed  The `matlabpool` function has been
>   removed. Compatibility Considerations  Calling `matlabpool` now
>   generates an error. You should instead use [`parpool`](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html) to create a
>   parallel pool.

`matlabpool('size')` does exactly what you'd expect it to do: it gives you the size of the current pool, i.e. the amount of workers assigned to it. [`gcp`](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gcp.html) (*GetCurrentPool*) does this for you. Its documentation's first example:

```
p = gcp('nocreate'); % If no pool, do not create new one.
if isempty(p)
    poolsize = 0;
else
    poolsize = p.NumWorkers
end
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I can't replace it with parpool without knowing what matlabpool('size') does, in the first place. I tried to google matlabpool documentation, but all the links were about parpool

Comment: Actually, it uses parfor if matlabpool('size') is not 0. I guess that was an issue in previous versions. I just removed that part of the if statement. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I know :) I think in previous versions, if you use parfor without actually creating parallel workers, it will throw an error. Now it just creates a new parallel pool automatically.

Comment: Nonetheless this is a good check to perform; I assume `m` is the number of iterations your loop has to do, and if your parallel pool isn't open, it's not worth time-wise to create one if you have only a few (`<100`) iterations. Smart and efficient coding this is. Using the example given in the `gcp` docs, you'd check that with `poolsize==0`, or initially in the `if` statement the `isempty(p)` code.